# python class fail to provide _Secretive__xxx() function, why?

Tags: python, function, class, call, private

I was trying to see if I can call a private function of a python class, I tried in ipython:

```
In [14]: class C:
   ....:     def __my(s):
   ....:         print "hello"
   ....:       

In [15]: print C
__main__.C

In [16]: obj=C()

In [17]: obj._Secretive__my
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c68d82fedeb4> in <module>()
----> 1 obj._Secretive__my

AttributeError: C instance has no attribute '_Secretive__my'
In [18]: obj._Secretive__my()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-ab4a9965f82a> in <module>()
----> 1 obj._Secretive__my()
```

Well, seems I cannot stat it or call it, right? Where did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you implement “Private” instance variable called **name mangling**. See doc [Private Variables and Class-local References](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

> ... such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

Try this:

```
obj._C__my
obj._C__my()
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of the method is [preceded](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) by `_` and the class name (`C`):

```
>>> class C:
...   def __my(self):
...     print "hello"
... 
>>> obj = C()
>>> dir(obj)
['_C__my', '__doc__', '__module__']
>>> obj._C__my()
hello
```

So, you *can* call the method, but the bizarre naming transformation is supposed to make you think twice about doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Double underscore prefix names get [mangled using the class name](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) - i.e. `C`, in this case:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __my(self):
...         print('hello')
...         
>>> obj = C()
>>> obj._C__my()
hello
```

**Do not use this feature to try and indicate a method is "private"**.  For that purpose, just use a single underscore.  The name mangling feature is for preventing name collisions in some rare and complicated inheritance situations.